# Trying to stop water in my basement

Tags: water, repair, basement, leak

Bought century home and had issue with water in the basement. Changed the grading around most of the house and installed a sump pump, this has solved most my problems. But there is an open 1 1/4in pipe I that is slowly leaking water into my basement especially when it rains. There is garage that it looks like the pipe direction is heading. I want to plug it up if it’s an old well line but some mentioned it might cause pressure with build of after. Anyone have idea on how to plug this pipe or what to do with it?

Comment: "if it’s an old well line" You need to KNOW what that line is before doing anything.

Comment: attach an albow and a vertical section of pipe

Comment: You would just be damming the thing up. It'll still be full of water and who knows how high of an inlet it has (high inlet implies high pressure). You need to find its other end. Maybe yell into it with somebody putzing around outside? Maybe push compressed air through it for the noise at the other orifice? Maybe push water through it if you're desperate enough?

Comment: What elevation is the pipe measured from the ground's surface outside? From the basement floor? A picture could be useful, with somebody instantly recognizing it.

Comment: The stable water height in @jsotola's pipe would tell you the height of the water supply's free surface, where that could be very useful in tracking the source.